# "is MovieClip" is true, yet compiler insists it is not and throws Error #1034: Type Coercion failed? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have in my library, various food icons converted and linked as MovieClips which i add to the scene dynamically. I'm trying to move them from one container to another. Containers are also dynamically added MovieClips.

I've been trying to move these icons who are "MovieClip extended class" instances to another MovieClip as child, by drag and drop, yet currentTarget in drop(it is fine in drag) is not recognised as MovieClip even with "currentTarget as MovieClip" and compiler throws error. Every trace indicates that it is indeed a MovieClip though. I'm at my wits end.

The "plate.addChild(mc);" is causing the error during dropping into the "plate" from "shelves".

The .fla file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApqQOqYhGvWHget1A4YRqyzT3a9BEQ?e=9UJB0R

```
    import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

/*;
choValues = {

    "apple": 15,
    "bakedBeans": 15,
    "chickenLeg": 0,
    "chickenNuggets": 15,
    "cornOnTheCob": 15,
    "egg": 0,
    "grapes": 5,
    "hamburger": 30,
    "milkFull": 24,
    "juiceFull": 30,
    "juiceHalf": 15,
    "saltineCrackers": 5,
    "orange": 15,
    "tomato": 5
}*/


var foodNames:Array = new Array();
var choValues:Array = new Array();
var options:Array = new Array();
var index:Array = new Array();
var shelves:MovieClip = new Shelves();
var plate:MovieClip = new Plate();
var plateSlots:Array = [0,0,0,0];
var iconSize:Array = new Array();

trace(stage.stageWidth);    
trace(stage.stageHeight);

var relativeWidth:Number = stage.stageWidth/32;
var relativeHeight:Number = stage.stageHeight/32;

trace("shelves");
trace(shelves.x = relativeWidth*4 );
trace(shelves.y = relativeHeight*8);
trace(shelves.width = relativeWidth*10);
trace(shelves.height = relativeHeight*14);
stage.addChildAt(shelves,1);

trace("plate");
plate.instanceName = "plate";
trace(plate.x = relativeWidth*15 );
trace(plate.y = relativeHeight*8);
trace(plate.width = relativeWidth*10);
trace(plate.height = relativeHeight*14);
plate.name = "plate";
stage.addChildAt(plate,0);

trace("plate.name "+ plate.name); 
/*var fruit = new orange;
trace("fruit");
trace(fruit.x = plate.width/2);
trace(fruit.y = plate.height/2);
//trace(plateSlots.width = plate.width/2);
//trace(plateSlots.height = plate.height/2);*/


//plate.addChild(fruit);


function drag (e:MouseEvent):void //find the slot
{
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
    trace("drag "+e.currentTarget.name);
    trace("Classname "+ getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget));
}

function drop (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    trace("drop Classname "+ getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget));
    trace("drop name "+ (e.currentTarget.name));
    //if(e.currentTarget.dropTarget !=null)
    //if(e.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent !=null)
    //if(e.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent.parent != null)
        try{if (e.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent.parent.name == "plate")
        {
            trace("currentTarget is "+e.currentTarget);

            var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
            trace(mc);
            trace("mc is movieClip?" + (mc is MovieClip));
            trace("is plate");
            for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
                if (plateSlots[i] == 0)
                {   
                    trace(mc);
                    //shelves.removeChild(mc);
                    plate.addChild(mc);
                    //e.currentTarget.width = iconSize[0];
                    //e.currentTarget.height = iconSize[1];
                    trace(mc.x = plate.width/6 + ((i%2)*plate.width/8));
                    trace(mc.y = plate.height/6 + ((i<2 ? 0:1)*plate.height/4));
                    plateSlots[i] = 1;
                    mc.slot = i;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
            else{
                    shelves.addChild(e.currentTarget as MovieClip);
                    e.currentTarget.x = e.currentTarget.oldX;
                    e.currentTarget.y = e.currentTarget.oldY;   
            }
        }
        catch(e:Error){}
            shelves.addChild(e.currentTarget as MovieClip);
            e.currentTarget.x = e.currentTarget.oldX;
            e.currentTarget.y = e.currentTarget.oldY;   


}

function randomize ( a : *, b : * ) : int {
    return ( Math.random() > .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

foodNames.push(
    "apple","bakedBeans","chickenLeg",
    "chickenNuggets","cornOnTheCob","egg",
    "grapes","hamburger","milkFull",
    "juiceFull","juiceHalf","saltineCrackers",
    "orange","tomato"
)

choValues.push(
    15,15,0,
    15,15,0,
    5,30,24,
    30,15,5,
    15,5
)

for (var i:int=1; i<foodNames.length; i++)
{
    index.push(i);
}

index.sort(randomize);
trace(index);

for(i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    options[index[i]] = new (getDefinitionByName(foodNames[index[i]]));
    trace("class "+getDefinitionByName(foodNames[index[i]]));
    options[index[i]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    options[index[i]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

    options[index[i]].CHO = choValues[i];

    options[index[i]].x += ( (2*(i%4)) +1 )    *(shelves.width /10);
    options[index[i]].y = ( ( i<4 ) ? 17 : 37 )*(shelves.height/64);

    options[index[i]].oldX = options[index[i]].x;
    options[index[i]].oldY = options[index[i]].y;

    shelves.addChild(options[index[i]]);
}
//iconSize[0] = options[index[0]].width;
//iconSize[1] = options[index[0]].height;
stop();
```

Comment: First, your `index` array does not hold a 0, thus you'll never have "apple"s in your app. Also random sort is better done with insertion at random instead of running sort(randomize). And most likely you need to use `e.target` instead of `e.currentTarget`. The `target` is the object that has received this event, and `currentTarget` is whatever parent of target that has a listener and has caught the event while it bubbles up the display list. Also, what object(s) has `MouseEvent` listeners `drag` and `drop` attached? I don't have Adobe Flash here to investigate.

Comment: @Vesper Thank you for your feedback. I first tried it with target but it led to weird behavior where food icons won't be dragged but instead spasm(?) or act like stuck. Listeners are attached to the food icons in "options" array in the bottom loop before they are added as children, and they are the only listeners. Also I thought I would need the randomised index array later on to keep tabs on which icons I will have added.

Comment: Hmmm. It's possible that some of your classes from `foodNames` is not an MC descendant indeed. Maybe `Sprite` or `Shape`. Check if `getQualifiedSuperclassName()` returns a `MovieClip` for each class from `foodNames`. `trace("superclass "+getQualifiedSuperclassName(options[index[i]]));`

Comment: Update: `dropTarget` is a property available in `Sprite` and its descendants, so having `Sprite` in superclass is OK, but `Shape` is not.

Comment: @Vesper I tried tracing each class as you suggested, the result is that they are indeed MovieClip. Output for each class: "superclass flash.display::MovieClip"

Comment: @Vesper I have finally fixed it with changing "stage.addChild(shelves)" and " stage.addChild(plate)" to "this.addChild(shelves)" and " this.addChild(plate)". I have no idea why though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have there several references to `parent.parent`, in some cases this might refer the stage, say if you're dropping a dragged object over some empty space, and `Stage` is not a `MovieClip`.

Comment: @Vesper That makes sense! Thanks for explaining!